# Nested dynamic form creation - State shared for dynamic added fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I´m trying to create a nested dynamic form using react that is able to generate dynamic input fields based on already generated dynamic input fields.

**What am I trying to do?**

User should be able to create a playlist that consists of

- Playlistname (1:1/ only once per form)
- YoutubeURL (As much as the user wants can be added
- StartTime/ EndTime (As much as the user wants can be added **to EACH youtubeURL**)

This is the starting form

[image: Playlist-Start]

I´m already able to add new Start/End-Time fields to a youtubeURL

[image]

But if I afterwards click on "add new fields" and generate a new input for youtubeURL, the generated Start/End time already share the state of the previous entered Start/end from the old youtubeURL.

I don't get where I´m doing this wrong.

[image]

And also overall the form doesn't feel like beeing really stable right now...
If someone has an idea how I can improve this form and also fix my shared state issue, would be great.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";

const PlaylistForm = () => {
  const [formPlaylistName, setFormPlaylistName] = useState("");
  const [formPlaylistYoutubeUrl, setFormPlaylistYoutubeUrl] = useState([
    { youtubeUrl: "" },
  ]);
  const [formPlaylistYoutubeUrlPlayTimes, setFormPlaylistYoutubeUrlPlayTimes] =
    useState([{ start: 0, end: 0 }]);

  // start formPlaylistYoutubeUrl
  let handleChangePlaylistYoutubeUrl = (i: any, e: any) => {
    let newFormValues = [...formPlaylistYoutubeUrl];
    // @ts-expect-error: Let's ignore a compile error like this unreachable code
    newFormValues[i][e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    setFormPlaylistYoutubeUrl(newFormValues);
  };

  let addFormFieldsPlaylistYoutubeUrl = () => {
    setFormPlaylistYoutubeUrl([...formPlaylistYoutubeUrl, { youtubeUrl: "" }]);
  };

  let removeFormFieldsPlaylistYoutubeUrl = (i: any) => {
    let newFormValues = [...formPlaylistYoutubeUrl];
    newFormValues.splice(i, 1);
    setFormPlaylistYoutubeUrl(newFormValues);
  };

  // end formPlaylistYoutubeUrl

  //start formPlaylistYoutubeUrlPlayTimes
  let handleChangePlaylistYoutubeUrlPlayTimes = (i: any, e: any) => {
    let newFormValues = [...formPlaylistYoutubeUrlPlayTimes];
    console.log(e.target.value);
    // @ts-expect-error: Let's ignore a compile error like this unreachable code
    newFormValues[i][e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    setFormPlaylistYoutubeUrlPlayTimes(newFormValues);
  };

  let addFormFieldsPlaylistYoutubeUrlPlayTimes = () => {
    setFormPlaylistYoutubeUrlPlayTimes([
      ...formPlaylistYoutubeUrlPlayTimes,
      { start: 0, end: 0 },
    ]);
  };

  let removeFormFieldsPlaylistYoutubeUrlPlayTimes = (i: any) => {
    let newFormValues = [...formPlaylistYoutubeUrlPlayTimes];
    newFormValues.splice(i, 1);
    setFormPlaylistYoutubeUrlPlayTimes(newFormValues);
  };

  //end formPlaylistYoutubeUrlPlayTimes

  let handleSubmit = (event: any) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert(formPlaylistName);
    alert(JSON.stringify(formPlaylistYoutubeUrl));
    alert(JSON.stringify(formPlaylistYoutubeUrlPlayTimes));
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <label>Playlist name</label>
      <Form.Control
        type="text"
        name="playlistName"
        value={formPlaylistName}
        onChange={(e) => setFormPlaylistName(e.target.value)}
      />
      {formPlaylistYoutubeUrl.map((element, index) => (
        <div className="form-inline" key={index}>
          <label>Name</label>
          <Form.Control
            type="text"
            name="youtubeUrl"
            value={element.youtubeUrl || ""}
            onChange={(e) => handleChangePlaylistYoutubeUrl(index, e)}
          />

          {index ? (
            <button
              type="button"
              className="button remove"
              onClick={() => removeFormFieldsPlaylistYoutubeUrl(index)}
            >
              Remove
            </button>
          ) : null}

          {formPlaylistYoutubeUrlPlayTimes.map((element1, index1) => (
            <div className="form-inline" key={index1}>
              <label>Start time</label>
              <Form.Control
                type="text"
                name="start"
                value={element1.start || ""}
                onChange={(e) =>
                  handleChangePlaylistYoutubeUrlPlayTimes(index1, e)
                }
              />
              <label>End time</label>
              <Form.Control
                type="text"
                name="end"
                value={element1.end || ""}
                onChange={(e) =>
                  handleChangePlaylistYoutubeUrlPlayTimes(index1, e)
                }
              />
              {index1 ? (
                <div>
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    className="button remove"
                    onClick={() =>
                      removeFormFieldsPlaylistYoutubeUrlPlayTimes(index1)
                    }
                  >
                    Remove
                  </button>
                </div>
              ) : null}
              <button
                type="button"
                className="button add"
                onClick={() => addFormFieldsPlaylistYoutubeUrlPlayTimes()}
              >
                Add time
              </button>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      ))}

      <div className="button-section">
        <Button
          variant="primary"
          type="button"
          onClick={() => addFormFieldsPlaylistYoutubeUrl()}
        >
          Add new Field
        </Button>
        <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
          Create new shorturl
        </Button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

export default PlaylistForm;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem why you share the state values after generating new input fields for time is that `index1` will always start at 0 and will therefore have the same state.

By splitting up `formPlaylistName` and `formPlaylistYoutubeUrl` you also make it from my perspective harder to keep a relation between those states. But this is quite important as 1 youtubeURL can have N timeInputs. In order to easier handle the form generation and updating you could combine `formPlaylistName` and `formPlaylistYoutubeUrl`.

```
  const [formPlaylistYoutubeUrl, setFormPlaylistYoutubeUrl] = useState([
    { youtubeUrl: "", times: [{ start: 0, end: 0 }] },
  ]);
```

Then change your onChange handler for the timeInputs:

```
  let addFormFieldsPlaylistYoutubeUrlPlayTimes = (index: any) => {
    let newFormValues = [...formPlaylistYoutubeUrl];
    console.log(formPlaylistYoutubeUrl);
    newFormValues[index].times.push({ start: 0, end: 0 });
    setFormPlaylistYoutubeUrl(newFormValues);
  };

  let removeFormFieldsPlaylistYoutubeUrlPlayTimes = (index: any, i: any) => {
    let newFormValues = [...formPlaylistYoutubeUrl];
    newFormValues[index].times.splice(i, 1);
    setFormPlaylistYoutubeUrl(newFormValues);
  }; 

 let handleChangePlaylistYoutubeUrlPlayTimes = (
    index: any,
    i: any,
    e: any
  ) => {
    console.log("CHANGE");
    let newFormValues = [...formPlaylistYoutubeUrl];
    // @ts-expect-error: Let's ignore a compile error like this unreachable code
    newFormValues[index].times[i][e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    setFormPlaylistYoutubeUrl(newFormValues);
  };
```

And exchange your `forPlaylistYoutubeUrlPlaytimes.map` function with this part:

```
  {formPlaylistYoutubeUrl[index].times.map((element1, index1) => (
  <div>
    <label>Start time</label>
    <Form.Control
      type="text"
      name="start"
      value={element1.start || ""}
      onChange={(e1) =>
        handleChangePlaylistYoutubeUrlPlayTimes(
          index,
          index1,
          e1
        )
      }
    />
    <label>End time</label>
    <Form.Control
      type="text"
      name="end"
      value={element1.end || ""}
      onChange={(e2) =>
        handleChangePlaylistYoutubeUrlPlayTimes(
          index,
          index1,
          e2
        )
      }
    />
    {index1 ? (
      <div>
        <button
          type="button"
          className="button remove"
          onClick={() =>
            removeFormFieldsPlaylistYoutubeUrlPlayTimes(
              index,
              index1
            )
          }
        >
          Remove TIMES
        </button>
      </div>
    ) : null}
  </div>
))}
```

This should basically do the trick. And also don't forget to adjust your PlaylistFormField generation to fit the new initial state:

```
  let addFormFieldsPlaylistYoutubeUrl = () => {
    setFormPlaylistYoutubeUrl([
      ...formPlaylistYoutubeUrl,
      { youtubeUrl: "", times: [{ start: 0, end: 0 }] },
    ]);
  };
```